# jQuery Breaking Navbar Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have noticed that when I click the navbar toggle to dropdown nav-links, it works fine, but when I click again to bring them back up, it doesn't work. I have noticed that this is due to jQuery being used in my code. I am unsure how to go about solving this, any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p-md-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-1">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand col-4"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Bastion Logo"></a>

      <div class="d-flex col-6 align-items-center">
        <h6 class="menuItem text-dark hover-underline-animation-navitem pb-1"><a href="mailto:support@bastiontech.co.uk" class="menuItem text-dark text-decoration-none">support@bastiontech.co.uk</a></h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler text-bg-dark" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <div class="mx-auto"></div>

      <div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item hover-underline-animation-navitem">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link menuItem text-dark">Website Design</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item hover-underline-animation-navitem">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link menuItem text-dark">SEO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item hover-underline-animation-navitem">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link menuItem text-dark">Power Apps</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item hover-underline-animation-navitem">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link menuItem text-dark">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item btn Audit btn-md text-white">
            Free Audit
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: We need to see more code, like your nav bar. What triggers the dropdown of the nav bar.

Comment: I have edited the initial post to show my navbar code

Comment: You've shown markup, not code. Apparently your custom jQuery script is conflicting with Bootstrap's scripts. As you can see above, the button works with jQuery loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what should I look to change if the scripts are conflicting please?